# How to remove MaterialCardView borders

Tags: android, android-layout, border, android-cardview, materialcardview

I'm using this layout

```
<android.support.design.card.MaterialCardView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:innerRadius="0dp"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thicknessRatio="0"
    app:cardCornerRadius="24dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="0dp"
    card_view:cardMaxElevation="0dp">
  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/close_button"
      android:layout_width="48dp"
      android:layout_height="48dp"
      android:layout_gravity="top|end"
      android:padding="@dimen/account_menu_close_button_padding"
      android:alpha="0"
      app:srcCompat="@drawable/quantum_gm_ic_close_vd_theme_24"
      />
</android.support.design.card.MaterialCardView>
```

but I get a cardView with tiny border

[image]

How can I remove this border and make the cardview transparent?

I saw this similar post, but it gives no answer

Comment: You can try app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use the [`MaterialCard`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/MaterialCardView.md) included in the [Material Components library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android) that extends the `androidx.cardview.widget.CardView` (the old CardView included in support library).

You can change the border using the **`app:strokeWidth`** attribute. The default value is 0.

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    app:strokeColor="@color/..."
    app:strokeWidth="xxdp"
    ../>
```

Comment: If the default value is 0, how come the stroke appears ? When I set it to 0, I don't see it anymore...

Comment: @androiddeveloper. I faced this problem! when I migrated from material 2 to material 3. it might be inherit from somewhere else by default .

Answer (score 9):

Have you used these,

```
app:strokeColor
app:strokeWidth
```

Comment: Assign a value of 1dp so; app:strokeColor="1dp". and give app:strokeWidth the color of your MaterialCardView

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem with card border and i did solved it with by adding cardElevation instead of normal elevation in card now the border has gone but remember it would not work in normal button only in material button.
android:cardElevation="0dp"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).